# Webview Bookmark

Tags: java, android, android-webview, bookmarks

I am trying to add bookmark in my web browser and have added it but , it is only saving 1 link . for example if I am at https://www.wikipedia.org/ and save this bookmark
    and i browse wikipedia more and landed on this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Featured_content
        the bookmark will show remove in snack bar and is just saving 1 link and removing 1 link
        I want to save both links.

```
  public static final String PREFERENCES = "PREFERENCES_NAME";
    public static final String WEB_LINKS = "links";
    public static final String WEB_TITLE = "title";
    String murl;
    //
    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    //
    android.webkit.WebView webView;

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack();
                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
         webView = (android.webkit.WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
         progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        initWebview();
         WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        murl = getIntent().getExtras().getString("url");

        coordinatorLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_content);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        // zoom
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        // zoom
        settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);

        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(webView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl(murl);
       webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    //    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
       // settings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);

        settings.setSaveFormData(true);
        settings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.saved, menu);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String links = sharedPreferences.getString(WEB_LINKS, null);

        if (links != null) {

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            ArrayList<String> linkList = gson.fromJson(links, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
            }.getType());

            if (linkList.contains(murl)) {
                menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.bookmark);
            } else {
                menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.bookmark);
            }
        } else {
            menu.getItem(0).setIcon(R.drawable.bookmark);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_bookmark) {

            String message;

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String jsonLink = sharedPreferences.getString(WEB_LINKS, null);
            String jsonTitle = sharedPreferences.getString(WEB_TITLE, null);


            if (jsonLink != null && jsonTitle != null) {

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                ArrayList<String> linkList = gson.fromJson(jsonLink, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
                }.getType());

                ArrayList<String> titleList = gson.fromJson(jsonTitle, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {
                }.getType());
                if (linkList.contains(murl)) {
                    linkList.remove(murl);
                    titleList.remove(webView.getTitle().trim());
                    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString(WEB_LINKS, new Gson().toJson(linkList));
                    editor.putString(WEB_TITLE, new Gson().toJson(titleList));
                    editor.apply();


                    message = "removed";

                } else {
                    linkList.add(murl);
                    titleList.add(webView.getTitle().trim());
                    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putString(WEB_LINKS, new Gson().toJson(linkList));
                    editor.putString(WEB_TITLE, new Gson().toJson(titleList));
                    editor.apply();

                    message = "Saved";
                }
            } else {

                ArrayList<String> linkList = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();
                linkList.add(murl);
                titleList.add(webView.getTitle());
                Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(WEB_LINKS, new Gson().toJson(linkList));
                editor.putString(WEB_TITLE, new Gson().toJson(titleList));
                editor.apply();

                message = "Saved";
            }

            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.show();

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void initWebview() {
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(android.webkit.WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                murl = url;
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView view, String url) {
                webView.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    webView.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
                super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        });


    }
}







xml file : 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```